# Recording custom dimensional metrics in New Relic

Tags: node.js, prometheus, metrics, newrelic

I’m looking for a way to record custom metrics with multiple dimensions using the node.js new-relic agent. From what I see, the API for custom metrics includes only [a name and a value](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/nodejs-agent/api-guides/nodejs-agent-api/#record_metric).

Is it possible to add labels to a metric so it can be queried according to multiple dimensions? For example, when I record metrics [with Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/data_model/#metric-names-and-labels) for my caching system, I add labels like:

- server name
- cache entry name
- tenant ID
- web API route

This allows me to aggregate my data according to different labels for different KPI dashboards (by tenant, by web API, etc).

Is this possible directly with New Relic? (I’m not asking about New Relic Prometheus integration)

It seems odd that the API is so simplistic when New Relic clearly [supports dimensional metrics](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/telemetry-data-platform/understand-data/new-relic-data-types/#dimensional-metrics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APM generally records non-dimensional metrics which are called [metric timeslice data](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/telemetry-data-platform/understand-data/metric-data/query-apm-metric-timeslice-data-nrql/).  I don't know the underlying reason for the difference, but I suspect it is simply due to the fact APM was New Relic's first product and dimensional metrics likely weren't implemented at the time.  I haven't confirmed, but `recordMetric()` probably uses timeslice metrics.

There are two main ways around this:

1. APM transactions are dimensional.  If the metrics are transaction-specific you can instead call [`newrelic.addCustomAttribute('key1', 'value1')`](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/nodejs-agent/api-guides/nodejs-agent-api/#add-custom-attribute) multiple times to attach dimensions to the transaction.  You can then query using NRQL.  For example: `FROM Transaction SELECT * WHERE key1 = 'value1' FACET key2`.
2. Call the [metrics API](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/telemetry-data-platform/ingest-apis/report-metrics-metric-api/) directly.  This lets you send dimensional metrics which will not be attached to the application, though of course one of the attributes can be the app name.  It is then similarly queryable through NRQL: `FROM Metric SELECT * WHERE key1 = 'value1' FACET key2`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions! For me, though, both of these options are sub-optimal. The first forces me into a flat structure because I am on already on an existing metric. That means I probably won't get percentile data and the like on it, and also won't easily be able to record multiple accesses to the same cache in the same transaction. The second option I would be afraid to use from a performance perspective. 
I did receive a satisfactory answer on the new relic forum however, which I'll post below.

Comment: @joniba "won't easily be able to record multiple accesses to the same cache in the same transaction" -> this sounds like you may want events, which themselves can contain metrics.  You could also treat the cache as a "data source" and it would show up in the appropriate place in APM with the other databases.  If it's not auto-instrumented it's relatively easy to do with a shim: https://newrelic.github.io/node-newrelic/docs/tutorial-Datastore-Simple.html.

Comment: "The second option I would be afraid to use from a performance perspective" -> The SDK will call the metrics API behind the scenes, so it's essentially the same.  This would publish a custom metric that's not tied to your application and would be queryable like in my example.

Comment: "The first forces me into a flat structure because I am on already on an existing metric" -> that's correct.  With the metrics API you can send nested JSON, though when you're querying it's visually flattened with periods in between.

Comment: "That means I probably won't get percentile data and the like on it" -> you can calculate percentiles on the fly: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/query-your-data/nrql-new-relic-query-language/get-started/nrql-syntax-clauses-functions/#func-percentile.  New Relic won't auto-calculate percentiles so if you don't send them you generally need to calculate ad-hoc.  However, you can convert events/metrics to new metrics, in which case they'll be ready to go when you query: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/telemetry-data-platform/convert-to-metrics/create-metrics-other-data-types/.

Comment: Wow that's a lot of great information for me to read over, thank you. I didn't know the Telemetry SDK just calls the metrics API underneath, although I did see that they batch calls. TBH, the main reason behind my question is to see if New Relic can compare to Prometheus, and the most worrying thing in this comparison is the performance. But your last suggestion, of creating metrics from other events, might give a solution to that.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/recording-custom-metrics-with-multiple-labels-in-node-js/154876) on the newrelic forum, this is possible using the [New Relic Telemetry SDK for node.js](https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-telemetry-sdk-node).

Comment: Right, the answer there suggests calling the metrics API directly like I had suggested or using the SDK which is a wrapper.  I guess the SDK is better than going custom.  There is also an events API if that fits your use case better.